# Does the sentence "To get back to the main point, the budget needs to be bigger" make sense to you?

Tags: infinitives, adjuncts

> **To get back to** the main point, **the budget** needs to be bigger.([source](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/grammaire-grammar/absolu-absolute-eng.html))

Does this sentence make sense?

I think the infinitive phrase "to get back to the main point" is an adverbial clause modifying "need to" in the main clause. It tells us the reason why the budget should be increased. The sentence should be "**To get back to** the main point, **we** need to increase the budget."

Answer (score 2):

As the source says *Some participle and infinitive phrases are common expressions that are considered absolute.*

In this example *To get back to the main point* is serving to redirect the focus of the narrative from details to central idea.  It doesn't really have any meaning associated the sentence, it just directs the readers attention.

It basically means *I have been discussing a bunch of things that are interesting, but not essential.  Now I am going to **return** to discussing the thing that is essential, which is:*

Your change is ok, if the central thesis is that ***we** need to increase the budget.*  The sentence was fine before, though - if the most important takeaway was that ***the budget** needs to be bigger.*

Comment: Thank you. In the sentence "To create meaning, the sentence must be attached to a RELATED sentence."(cited ftom http://www.gcisd-k12.org/Page/19551), does the infinitive phrase "To create meaning" also function as an absolute phrase?

Comment: @April - Yes, it does. You seem to be getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

"To get back to the main point" is a way to segue from a tangential discussion back to the central theme. It is a self-referential statement like "But I digress...". The sentence could be punctuated like this:

**To get back to the main point — the budget needs to be increased.**